# CSS Inheritance not working correctly for tabs

Tags: html, css

I've fairly simple CSS code for my tabs. Problem is I'm adding this as part of larger CSS base and I keep getting it overwritten by defaults. For example I have a `* { font-size: 8pt; }` which forces itself into my new added CSS.

````css
/*
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
*/

/*
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css');
*/

/*
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
*/

.tabsWrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px auto;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}

.tabs {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    /*
    display: inline-block;
*/
    /*
    border-radius: 50px;
*/
    position: relative;
}

.tabs a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.tabs a.active {
    color: #fff;
}

.tabs a i {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.tabs .selector {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    /*
    border-radius: 50px;
    */
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    background: #05abe0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#05abe0', endColorstr='#8200f4', GradientType=1);
}

.tabs-content {
    display: none;
}

.tabs-content.active {
    display: block;
}```
/*
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
*/

/*
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css');
*/

/*
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
*/

.tabsWrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px auto;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}

.tabs {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    /*
    display: inline-block;
*/
    /*
    border-radius: 50px;
*/
    position: relative;
}

.tabs a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.tabs a.active {
    color: #fff;
}

.tabs a i {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.tabs .selector {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    /*
    border-radius: 50px;
    */
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    background: #05abe0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#05abe0', endColorstr='#8200f4', GradientType=1);
}

.tabs-content {
    display: none;
}

.tabs-content.active {
    display: block;
}
````

```html
<body>
    <div class="tabsWrapper">
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="selector"></div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active" data-id="Tab-40w1lgn2"><i class="fas fa-bomb">Test
                </i>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="Tab-w2mo0zn9"><i class="fas fa-bomb">Test5
                </i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My understanding was that if I add !Important for tabs CSS it would make sure that everything down of tabs gets that setting including A/I and so on. But it doesn't work. It only works if I move font-size down to A/I element which is not what I want. I would like to make sure that settings go down properly to the elements below. What is the easiest way?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal selector will be applied to each and every element. Even when the font-size is set on `.tabs`, the `*` will set font-size again on the `a` and `i` children.

If you want to have proper inheritance, use

```
body {
  font-size: 8pt;
}
```

This will keep the `8pt` size until an element defines another size.

Some more information [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-using-the-universal-selector-if-we-can-apply-a-css-rule-for-the-whole-document-using-body-or-html)

Comment: So if I will avoid `* {}` my assumption that everything under tabs will get proper styling is correct?

Comment: as long as there are no other more specific selectors for the children, yes

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because your include: `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');` is commented out?

Comment: Nope, it's not related. It's strictly related to * { } going down everywhere unless element has a direct definition preventing it.